# Make POST request with PHP and Json

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Good day guys..... please i need a hint on how to make a post request with json and php..

i am new to json so i dont really understand their code struture... i was given some line of json code to work with an api. below is the code.

```
{
  "secret_key": "<YOUR SECRET KEY>",
  "service": "fly_buy",
  "service_method": "post",
  "service_version": "v1",
  "service_channel": "rave",
  "service_payload": {
    "Country": "",
    "CustomerId": "+1111111111",
    "Reference": "9300049404444",
    "Amount": 0,
    "RecurringType": 0,
    "IsAirtime": true,
    "BillerName": "AIRTIME"
  }
}
```

this is my html form code for sending the request

```
<div id="bills2" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <!–– List group item ––>
    <div id="airtime_panel" class="container">
<form class="jumbotron">
  <div class="form-group" align="center">

  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustomerId"  placeholder="Mobile Number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="E-mail">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Amount" placeholder="Amount">
  </div>
  <div  class="row" align="center">
  <div class="col" align="center">
   <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Buy Airtime</button>
   <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back </button>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
   </div>

</div>
```

i will like to know if am doing the right thing. Thanks

Comment: check [this](https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl) article.. after receiving data on server you need to hit the API using cURL.

Comment: thanks @jagad89 let me go through it